# How to install printer drivers on Arch Linux when there is no official Arch package provided?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, drivers, printing, compatibility

I am trying to print to Epson WorkForce WF-2650 All-In-One Inkjet PRinter from my Arch Linux desktop. Both the desktop and the printer are in network range `192.168.0.1/24`.

1. Initialize Printer Service

The first thing I did was to install CUPS.

```
sudo pacman -Syu cups cups-pdf
```

Then I enabled then started the service.

```
sudo systemctl enable cups
sudo systemctl start cups
```

2. Add Printer

After setting up the printing service I tried to add the printer via Gnome Print. I was able to locate the printer by ip but as soon as clicked add I got `Failed to add new printer.`

Since that failed I moved to the CUPS web page on `localhost:631`. On navigating `Administration > Printers > Add Printer` I saw my printer in `Discovered Network Printers`. When I hit `Continue` it identified the connection as `lpd://192.168.0.156:515/PASSTHRU`. However there were only two models to choose from: `9-Pin Series` and `24-Pin Series` which do not correspond to my printer.

So I fell back to the Generic drivers. I tried printing a small PDF file with the `Generic IPP Everywhere Printer` and `Generic PDF Printer` drivers but neither of them printed properly. In both cases I got plaintext gibberish.

Command `lpadmin -p WF2650 -E -v lpd://192.168.0.156:515 -m everywhere` did not work either, so I started searching for functional drivers.

3. Find Printer Drivers

When I searched [the official repository](https://archlinux.org/packages/?q=epson), I only found one package for scanner drivers and no printer drivers. Nonetheless I did try `sudo pacman -Syu imagescan` and it did succeed but no printer drivers.

Then I visited AUR and found a lot of [Epson-related packages](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages?O=0&K=epson). There were two AURs and I wasn't sure which one covered my printer so I tried both.

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2

For both AURs I downloaded the snapshot containing the `PKGBUILD`, extracted then cd'd to it. Then I downloaded the source in that directory and tried to install each. Unfortunately both attempts failed.

```
sudo pacman -U ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2-1.2.3-1.tar.gz 
loading packages...
error: missing package metadata in ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2-1.2.3-1.tar.gz
error: './epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2-1.2.3-1.tar.gz': invalid or corrupted package
```

```
sudo pacman -U ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr-1.8.0-1.src.rpm 
loading packages...
error: missing package metadata in ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr-1.8.0-1.src.rpm
error: './epson-inkjet-printer-escpr-1.8.0-1.src.rpm': invalid or corrupted package
```

Then I went to the official Epson download page and [searched](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule). Unfortunately only [`deb` and `rpm` packages are provided](https://support.epson.net/linux/Printer/LSB_distribution_pages/en/escpr.php). I considered converting one of the two into a compatible format but the site suggested against it.

> If you want to use the driver other than the above distribution,
> we recommend that you build from the source file and install it.

Is it okay install the `deb` package with `dpkg` on Arch? Would it break my system? If it is not an option what should I do from here?

Comment: https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-WF-2650_Series this is the dirver you need, i'm not familiar with arch but i see yu have found the aur who works for your printer https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr

Comment: this is how you build a package from aur https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_User_Repository you must have `base-devel` packet installed as they say below in the page.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force way is to extract the files from the `.deb` (or whatever else) and place them in the system paths on your computer. This is not a very clean way, and will cause some issues if you want to uninstall later because the pacman won't be aware of the files.

What you would need to do is instead write a `PKGBUILD` that does the same thing, so that the files can be installed *as a package*. But you don't need to do that because there is already an AUR package someone made.

Your problem is not about installing unofficial drivers, but about troubleshooting a general AUR install error. You should either edit this question, or ask a new one.